# Probability Tree with three events at the same time - Help!

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm not sure if the answers are right. I wonder if somebody could help me? Thanks

Consider a population of fish (of the same species) that have different color patterns.  30% of the fish are green, 20% of the fish are yellow, and 50% of the fish are blue.  The coloration patterns are independent of each other.  You will sample three fish at a time.

> **(a)** What is the probability you choose three green fish?

My attempt: $0.3 \times 0.3 \times 0.3 = 0.027$

> **(b)** What is the probability you choose two yellow and one blue fish, in any order?

My attempt:  $~~3p \cdot 2q =3(0.2 \times 0.2)\cdot (0.5) = 0.06$

> **(c)** What is the probability you choose three blue fish ***OR*** three yellow fish?

My attempt: $~~\Pr\{G ~\text{or}~ Y \} = \Pr\{~ 0.125~ \} + \Pr\{~0.008~\} = 0.001$

> **(d)** Is the probability of drawing one blue fish joint or disjoint with the probability of drawing one yellow fish?  Why?

**My attempt: ???**

Thanks!

Comment: For $3$ blue or $3$ yellow, the addition is not correct. Also, it should be Probability of Blue or Yellow $=0.125+0.008$, no $\Pr$ after the $=$ sign. For (d), the events $1$ blue and $1$ yellow are not disjoint, since it can perfectly well happen that one of our fish is blue **and** another is yellow.

Comment: A-c look good, except I don't understand, in c, why you don't simply sum 0.125 and 0.008. Answer should be their sum (and you might want to mention that - obviously - the intersection of the 2 events is empty (to justify your formula).

Comment: What does it mean that "the coloration patterns are independent of each other"?